# Error when installing CiviVolunteer

Tags: wordpress, installation, civivolunteer

Not sure how to resolve this. Getting the error when installing org.civicrm.volunteer

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. DB Error:
>   unknown error

Here is the backTrace log:

backTrace

```
0 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(187): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()

1 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))

2 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(984): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , extends_entity_col...")

3 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , extends_entity_col...")

4 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , extends_entity_col...", "DB_Error", TRUE)

5 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))

6 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, "INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , extends_entity_col...", "1292 ** Incorrect datetime value: '0' for column 'created_date' at row 1")

7 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()

8 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , extends_entity_col...")

9 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2446): DB_common->query("INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , extends_entity_col...")

10 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1068): DB_DataObject->_query("INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , extends_entity_col...")

11 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(495): DB_DataObject->insert()

12 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Migrate/Import.php(132): CRM_Core_DAO->save()

13 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Migrate/Import.php(213): CRM_Utils_Migrate_Import->copyData(Object(CRM_Core_DAO_CustomGroup), Object(SimpleXMLElement), TRUE, "name")

14 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Migrate/Import.php(80): CRM_Utils_Migrate_Import->customGroups(Object(SimpleXMLElement), (Array:2))

15 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/Upgrader.php(787): CRM_Utils_Migrate_Import->runXmlElement(Object(SimpleXMLElement))

16 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/Upgrader.php(48): CRM_Volunteer_Upgrader->executeCustomDataTemplateFile("volunteer-customdata.xml.tpl")

17 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/Upgrader/Base.php(306): CRM_Volunteer_Upgrader->install()

18 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/volunteer.civix.php(54): CRM_Volunteer_Upgrader_Base->onInstall()

19 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/volunteer.php(262): _volunteer_civix_civicrm_install()

20 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Manager/Module.php(76): volunteer_civicrm_install()

21 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Manager/Module.php(48): CRM_Extension_Manager_Module->callHook(Object(CRM_Extension_Info), "install")

22 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Manager.php(229): CRM_Extension_Manager_Module->onPreInstall(Object(CRM_Extension_Info))

23 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php(181): CRM_Extension_Manager->install((Array:1))

24 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(447): CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions->postProcess()

25 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(160): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()

26 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next", "Next")

27 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next")

28 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next")

29 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")

30 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(384): CRM_Core_Controller->run()

31 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(168): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->edit(1, NULL)

32 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php(121): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()

33 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(310): CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions->run((Array:3), NULL)

34 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))

35 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))

36 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1227): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))

37 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")

38 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))

39 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))

40 /home/replaced/domains/test.replaced.org/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(222): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")

41 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the trace it's importing from

`CRM_Volunteer_Upgrader->executeCustomDataTemplateFile("volunteer-customdata.xml.tpl")`

That causes the error:

`"INSERT INTO civicrm_custom_group (name , title , extends , extends_entity_col...", "1292 ** Incorrect datetime value: '0' for column 'created_date' at row 1"`

There's an [open issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/VOL-299) for this on CiviVolunteer that shows a workaround.

There's also [this issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19546), and I've had experience where I've just had to remove the `created_date` from the XML, so hopefully this will be resolved in the future.